# How to add an IP range to Lion server's SMTP whitelist

Tags: email, osx-server, serveradmin

I run Lion Server (10.7.5) on an old iMac (2.33 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo) and it handles my e-mail for me.

I've been having some trouble recently with delays in delivery of e-mail to my server from DynDNS's mail backup service. I have been advised to add DynDNS's IP range (216.146.32.0/23) to my whitelist.

Trawling the net has revealed how to add a single host to the whitelist (add it to `/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist`), but that IP range holds 512 hosts. Also, the Mac version of `/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist` contains the following text:

```
### DO NOT MANUALLY EDIT THIS FILE ###
# This file is automatically generated
# any manual additions to this file will be lost
```

which suggests to me that there is another way of doing it.

Can anyone enlighten me please?